# Reading from USB serial port under Cygwin

Tags: command-line, usb, cygwin, serial-port

I am actually using Cygwin, but it is my understanding that it responds to Unix commands so hopefully I am in the correct place.

I have an Arduino hooked up via USB to my LapTop for data reading.

I want to be able to simultaneously be able to output the serial port data to the shell for my viewing and also save all that data as a text file.

Is there a command I can use to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command [`tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) duplicates its input onto several output streams.

Cygwin presents serial ports as `/dev/ttyS0`, `/dev/ttyS1`, … corresponding to Windows's `COM1`, `COM2`, … (there's an offset of 1).

Figure out which serial port number Windows assigns to your serial device. Say the device is `COM4`:

```
tee </dev/ttyS3 serial-log.txt
```

Comment: One other thing, I was thinking of doing another thread on this, but I decided not to since it is directly related to this question. I want this command to be scheduled at a certain time. How can I do this since the AT command for cygwin has been deprecated? I tried echo "test" | at 17:50 but I get the error: please use schtasks.exe instead

Comment: @l3win That's a Cygwin question, and I can't help you with this one.

Comment: I tried this out and I discovered that both "at" and "schtasks" are Windows programs.  If there's an "at" for cygwin, we'd have to figure out which package it is in.

Comment: @l3win : even in CygWin you can simply use `crontab` to schedule. See this : http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72143/38817