# Run a command at a certain time in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, scheduling

I am writing a bash (.sh) script for cygwin. I want to run a certain command at specific time.

I tried the following:

```
echo "test" | at 19:00
```

but I get the following error:

```
The AT command has been deprecated. Please use schtasks.exe instead.
```

So can I only use Scheduled Task in Windows for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `at` command from Unix is not available on Cygwin. Cygwin has traditionally used the `at` command from windows, but this has been deprecated in favour of `schtasks.exe`.

So the answer to your question is yes: you can only use Scheduled Task in Windows for running a task once.

(You can use `cron` and set it on a specific date at a specific time... but it will repeat every year unless you remove the task from the crontab.) ;-)

Comment: All of my efforts to "run a command with arguments once at a specified time" have failed. `schtasks.exe` is NOT a suitable replacement for the unix `at` command. The later is actually usable.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead add a cron job.

Login from the user from which you want to execute the bash script.

Execute `crontab -e` command.

Now suppose if you want to run the bash script exactly on 19:00 on daily basis, then you need to add a line like this:

```
00 19 * * * /path/to/bash/script
```

Note: That script must have executable bit set for that user.

Comment: hmm... it does recognize crontab -e command. I looked it up online, it is my understanding that I need a cygrunsrv package for this

Comment: Cron is for periodic jobs. This question is about a once-off.

Comment: The answer is ok but you have to install the cron package first (using setup.exe of cygwin) .